# How to foster Qt Style sheets use at work?

Tags: qt, pyqt, stylesheet

I'm working with a PyQt application.
My workmates work with Java and they developed a whole framework (java code + xml files) to set different and new UIs to their desktop application.
I told them that Qt has styles sheets. I showed them by example how cool style sheets are.
I did not convince them. They want me to port their java framework to python.
I want to persuade them to use qt style sheets, but I need "serious" and technical arguments.
Examples are not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using Qt, you are using a commercially backed library that has a full support staff dedicated to maintaining it, not to mention the open source community that also supports it. You do not need to spend time and effort maintaining the UI framework so you can spend more time developing UI components specific to your applications.

Trying to develop a whole UI internally is a lot of work not only in implementation but also testing and maintenance. For such complicated systems, I would always recommend using an established library over doing an internal implementation.